# How to hide a column in SSRS Matrix report in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, ssrs-tablix

I've got a SSRS matrix report in VS2017. I need to hide a column based on no.of days in a month.

Eg: Need to hide 29,30 & 30th Column in case of Feb Month in pic provided below.

[image]

My report's Dataset consists of 38 columns, I found this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms157328(v=sql.90)) with settings as `=IIF(CountRows()>12,true,false)` but this still fails. My report still shows the 29,30 & 32 columns.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You say *"it still fails", what is the error then?

Comment: Amend your dataset to not return columns that contain no data

Comment: "It still fails" - Empty columns still exists

Comment: Update the question and show the output of the procedure or query of the dataset and a screenshot of the design of the report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the column to hide, right-click --> Column Visibility --> Show or hide based on an expression --> Click f(*x*) to provide expression as provided below

[image]

> =IIF(Count(Fields!.Value) = Cint(0), True, False)